# How can i view all cpus in top using a script on a multi core machine

Tags: linux, multicore

I am writing a script that uses "top" command.

When i use top i can see the average CPU USE:

> Cpu(s): 41.9%us,  9.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 48.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

i know i can press "1" to view each CPU separately:

> Cpu0  :  8.8%us,  3.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 85.5%id,  2.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
>
> Cpu1  :  9.7%us,  3.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 83.6%id,  3.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

but how can i integrate it into a script when i can't use keypresses?

Answer (score 1):

You can press 'W' to save your current state. That will generate a `.toprc` file in your user's home directory it will also mean that the next time you run top as that user all cores will be shown.

It will look something like:

```
RCfile for "top with windows"           # shameless braggin'
Id:a, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=3.000, Curwin=0
Def     fieldscur=AEHIOQTWKNMbcdfgjplrsuvyzX
        winflags=30009, sortindx=10, maxtasks=0
        summclr=1, msgsclr=1, headclr=3, taskclr=1
Job     fieldscur=ABcefgjlrstuvyzMKNHIWOPQDX
        winflags=62777, sortindx=0, maxtasks=0
        summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
Mem     fieldscur=ANOPQRSTUVbcdefgjlmyzWHIKX
        winflags=62777, sortindx=13, maxtasks=0
        summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
Usr     fieldscur=ABDECGfhijlopqrstuvyzMKNWX
        winflags=62777, sortindx=4, maxtasks=0
        summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=3
```

You can check out `man top` to understand most of this stuff or just screw around in top and 'W' to see what comes out the other end.

Comment: I saved two configurations, it seems the difference in the Single CPU setting is reflected in the `winflags` value, 193844 versus 161076 in my case.

Comment: I've never messed with this file, but I'm guessing since your values are different than mine that perhaps winflags is a bitmask. I'm betting it's the same bit in that integer that is flipped for that setting. Interesting stuff.